# SwiftUI: performance issue with UIViewControllerRepresentable UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swiftui, uipageviewcontroller, ios14

As pure SwiftUI PageViewControllers using `TabView` with `.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())` currently come with a severe lagging when swiping between pages, I tried to implement a PageViewController using `UIViewControllerRepresentable` and `UIPageViewController` as presented by Apple in the SwiftUI tutorial "Interfacing with UIKit" (https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit).

Unfortunately that PageViewController implementation invokes the `body` of *all pages* when the user first swipes a page (or first taps on a TextField), contradicting the basic idea of a PageViewController, which is loading only a couple of pages at a time. When working with a large number of pages and/or complex pages, the app ends being unusable because there is apparently no reaction to the first swipe or - when trying to enter text using a TextField - it can take a long while until letters typed on the keyboard are displayed in the TextField.

Is there a way to avoid this (mis)behaviour (tested on `Xcode 12.4` and `iOS 14.4`)?

To demonstrate I have created the following small project:

ContentView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let textArray = ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth",
        "Fifth", "Sixth", "Seventh", "Eighth", "Ninth", "Tenth"]

    var body: some View {
        PageView(pages: textArray.map { PageContentView(text: $0) })
    }
}
```

PageContentView (with a print statement that demonstrates the behaviour):

```
import SwiftUI

struct PageContentView: View {
    let text: String
    @State private var keyboardInput = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        print ("PageContentView body for: \(text)")
        return VStack {
            Text(text)
            TextField("Enter Text", text: $keyboardInput)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

The remaining views are taken as is from the tutorial (removing the PageControl part to simplify the example):

PageView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct PageView<Page: View>: View {
    var pages: [Page]
    @State private var currentPage = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        PageViewController(pages: pages, currentPage: $currentPage)
    }
}
```

PageViewController:

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct PageViewController<Page: View>: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var pages: [Page]
    @Binding var currentPage: Int

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIPageViewController {
        let pageViewController = UIPageViewController(
            transitionStyle: .scroll,
            navigationOrientation: .horizontal)
        pageViewController.dataSource = context.coordinator
        pageViewController.delegate = context.coordinator

        return pageViewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, context: Context) {
        pageViewController.setViewControllers(
            [context.coordinator.controllers[currentPage]], direction: .forward, animated: true)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {
        var parent: PageViewController
        var controllers = [UIViewController]()

        init(_ pageViewController: PageViewController) {
            parent = pageViewController
            controllers = parent.pages.map { UIHostingController(rootView: $0) }
        }

        func pageViewController(
            _ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
            viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
            guard let index = controllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) else {
                return nil
            }
            if index == 0 {
                return controllers.last
            }
            return controllers[index - 1]
        }

        func pageViewController(
            _ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
            viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
            guard let index = controllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) else {
                return nil
            }
            if index + 1 == controllers.count {
                return controllers.first
            }
            return controllers[index + 1]
        }

        func pageViewController(
            _ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
            didFinishAnimating finished: Bool,
            previousViewControllers: [UIViewController],
            transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
            if completed,
               let visibleViewController = pageViewController.viewControllers?.first,
               let index = controllers.firstIndex(of: visibleViewController) {
                parent.currentPage = index
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @loremipsum yes, please refer to the first sentence in my question.

Comment: Did you found a solution for your issue? I could fix it by creating the `UIHostingController` for each page on demand, rather than upfront.